# Eclipse (simulator Android tablet) File Not Found even though file exists

Tags: android, eclipse-rcp, simulator, file-not-found

I am trying to read a file.
I do not mind the location, so I have tried various locations and ways to do this:

```
File file = new File("DFirstPdf.pdf");
File file = new File("C:/DFirstPdf.pdf");
File file = new File("C:\\DFirstPdf.pdf");
```

But I always get that file does not exist. I am working whit Eclipse and a simulator and I do not have more ideas.

What I want to do is:
    if (file.exists())
    {
    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

if (activities.size() > 0) 
{
startActivity(intent);
}
else
{
// Do something else here. Maybe pop up a Dialog or Toast
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the classloader to get the resource

PackageManager.class.getClassLoader().getResource("DFirstPdf.pdf");

Comment: I have done the following code  File file = new File((PackageManager.class.getClassLoader().getResource("D://DFirstPdf.pdf").toURI()));  and File file = new File((PackageManager.class.getClassLoader().getResource("DFirstPdf.pdf").toURI())); but I get a Null Pinter Exception, Where show I have the file stored? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

THe simulator has its own filesystem.  It won't see files on your machine.  ANd it has a UNIX style path, not a windows style one.

Comment: So, How can I do to get a file.PDF, where Can I store it, to loading it after? any other suggestion?

Comment: Load it in your apk, or if you don't want all your users to have that file (its a test file, for example), put it on your emulator with adb push.  Your app can save it to the emulator's simulated internal or external storage.

Comment: That is a good idea, but, sorry, how can i do that, Its a test file I do not mind all users have it.